# flutter : Map method return dynamic not specific object

Tags: flutter, dart

I get JSON data from Api and with map method I changed map to my specific class :

```
  final result = await supaService.supabase.client
      .from('user_able')
      .select()
      .eq('user_id', uuid)
      .execute();

  final response = result.data[0]['user'];
  final databaseusers =
      response.map((e) => DataBaseModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Now I want to return **List** but I got :

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DataBaseModel>'
```

Why? Map method should return list of my object but it returns `dynamic`?

Comment: Is your .fromJson method a factory or a static method? If it is a static method, are you specifying its return type?

Comment: Please try this final databaseusers =
      response.map((e) => DataBaseModel.fromJson(e as DataBaseModel)).toList();

Comment: e is map bro @NandakishorDhanajiValakunde

Comment: It's maded by JSON serializer  library  `
  factory DataBaseModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$DataBaseModelFromJson(json);` @FabiánBardecio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast your list:

```
final databaseusers = response.map((e) => DataBaseModel.fromJson(e)).toList() as List<DataBaseModel>;
```

Also you can give a type when use the `map`

```
final databaseusers = response.map<DataBaseModel>((e) => DataBaseModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Comment: `final databaseusers = response.map<DataBaseModel>((e) => DataBaseModel.fromJson(e)).toList();` works . Thanks